# Stubbing file tests in shUnit2

Tags: bash, unit-testing, shunit2

I am using shUnit2 to do unit testing in Bash shell scripts.

I have code like this:

```
if [ ! -x /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm ]; then
  ...
fi
```

etc

I want to write unit tests to test this code, but to do that I need to stub out the behaviour of Bash file tests.

One way I could do this would be to refactor as:

```
if ! test -x /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm; then
  ...
fi
```

Then I can stub out the test built-in using something like:

```
test() {
  case "$*" in
  "-x /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm")
    false
    ;;
  esac
}
```

Creating the files that are expected during `setUp` might be an option sometimes, but obviously not always.

Or, I could refactor to move file tests inside custom functions, e.g.

```
rvm_installed() {
  [ -x /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm ]
}
```

Then I can stub this function in my tests.

Is there any way to test this code without refactoring it though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @janos said is correct, but it breaks shUnit2 if something like `[` is stubbed.

I raised a pull request that was merged to fix this problem in the way @janos suggested in the comments. This fix will hopefully be released eventually in shUnit2 2.1.7.

In the mean time the options are:

1) Use the patched version above.

2) See also suggestions about how to use a wrapper file in this example here: https://github.com/zofrex/bourne-shell-unit-testing

Answer (score 2):

You can stub `[` just as you can stub `test`:

```
[() {
  case "$*" in
  "-x /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm")
    false
    ;;
  esac
}
```

Comment: Wow. I never would have guessed you could do that.

Comment: Actually, as clever as this is, stubbing [ breaks shUnit2.

Comment: @AlexHarvey ouch. By the same logic, perhaps you cannot stub anything that might be used by `shUnit2` ? They could protect against that by using `command [` everywhere instead of `[`

Comment: Yes, why not? I might see if there is some way to patch it.